# How to use "sed" command to replace the tail of the string

Tags: sed

Here is a path string like that:

```
path=/home/test/test.xml
```

I want to change it to

```
path=******
```

How can I do for it?
I try to use "sed" to replace this string, but it cannot work as expected.

Comment: Why is this tagged tcl when it's asking about sed?

Comment: Fixed the tags.

Comment: Have you tried anytihng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just string from `echo` use `sed` with regex-replacement `sed -e 's#PARAM#REPLACEMENT#'`:

```
echo 'path=/home/test/test.xml' | sed -e 's#path=.*#path=******#'
```

If you want replace this string in file add `-i` flag and filename:

```
sed -i -e 's#path=.*#path=******#' file.name
```

FYI In this example `#` delimiter was used just for avoiding mess with escaping `*` characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'path=/home/test/test.xml'|sed 's@/home/test/test.xml@******@'
path=******
```

The character `@` here is *randomly* chosen, as it doesn't feature anywhere in the string.

The **common** delimiter would be a `/`, but that would require a lot of escaping in the path string.